# yii - variable available to each controller

Tags: yii, class-visibility, global-scope

I am new to yii.

I am using more than 1 controller in my website and each controller has few actions.

I want to use some variables across each controller (Value of variable will be fixed, I need some constants for a formula). Whats the best place (standard way) to define those variables ?
Should I use session ? (as value is not going to change).

Comment: Why -1 in my 3 questions at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are using your vars for, but you can do it by defining them in your config main.php

```
'params'=>array(
'someVar1'=>'varValue1',
    'someVar2' => 'varValue2',
),
```

Then you can access them in ANYWHERE by calling

```
Yii::app()->params['someVar1']
```

They will be available anywhere in your application.

Or you can extend all your controllers off of a base class and define your constants there

Base Controller:

```
class Controller extends CController { 

    const SOME_VAR = 'someValue'; 
}
```

Your controller:

```
class YourController1 extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo parent::SOME_VAR;
    }

}
```

Your other controller:

```
class YourController2 extends Controller
{
    public function actionLogin()
    {
         echo parent::SOME_VAR;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thx, I got my answer from yii forums,this is exactly what I am using.

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30868-variable-array-available-to-each-controller/